# Why do img elements behave different inside of a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have a flexbox with a `max-width: 500px`, and inside I have 3 `img` elements, they extend beyond the `max-width` of the flexbox.

However, if I wrap all of those `img` elements in a `div`, they remain contained within the `max-width` of the flexbox.

I thought it might be due to the `display` property, but changing the `img` element to `display: block` also doesn't keep it contained.

Overflow of flexbox:

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1586154/pexels-photo-1586154.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1586154/pexels-photo-1586154.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1586154/pexels-photo-1586154.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
</div>
```

Contained within flexbox:

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1586154/pexels-photo-1586154.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1586154/pexels-photo-1586154.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1586154/pexels-photo-1586154.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the trick is with the percentage used in width/max-width .. in the first case it's relative to the container (width:700px) and in the second case it's relative to the div which is a flex item and its size depend on the content (read the duplicate to understand this part)

Comment: @TemaniAfif It seems too obvious once you point that out...is there any way to keep all images contained inside of the flexbox without having to wrap them in all individual divs?

Comment: yes, min-width:0 to the image